# What is the antonym of "think highly of"?

Tags: antonyms

Consider the sentence "I think highly of you." A quick Google search reveals the opposite to be "I think slightly of you", but I have never heard anyone say that. Is there a more commonly used alternative?

Comment: I don’t think much of you [at all].

Comment: How about: "think poorly of"?  In that sense, "think highly of" = "think well of".

Comment: "I despise you."